# Reading netstat Output to Install Printer

Tags: port, netstat

Long story behind it, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I am working on a remote virtual machine implementation, where depending on the client device's location, the appropriate network printer will be installed via batch file (no VBS or PowerShell).

So, my idea is this:

1. Run netstat -an -p tcp to find the line containing port 49404.
2. Filter that output to grab the second IP address that will be
   returned
3. Replace last octet of that IP with "250" (the printer IP
   for each network)
4. Run nslookup on newly calculated IP to obtain
   the name of that printer
5. Install printer by name.

Here's what I do have so far, pieced together from older posts around the web (I haven't gotten to steps 4 or 5 yet):

```
@echo off
netstat -p tcp -an | FIND "49404" > %temp%\TEMPIP.txt
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (%temp%\TEMPIP.txt) do set IP=%%a
del %temp%\TEMPIP.txt
set IP=%IP:~9%
set "ip=%IP%"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%a in ("%ip%") do (
set octetA=%%a
set octetB=%%b
set octetC=%%c
set octetD=232
)
```

I'm sure there are cleaner or more efficient ways to perform this task, so I'm hoping you all can point me in the right direction.  Thanks!